# Open & populate infowindow via ajax on "click" with Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I am trying to populate a Google map infowindow with content from a partial (via ajax) when the map marker is clicked.

apneadivings wiki post here has helped: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Adding-an-id-to-markers-and-access-them-later

I do have the id for the model instance I want to retrieve in the marker (from the source: "marker.json({ :id => user.id })").  But I cannot figure out how to use this to attach a listener to the markers click action, and then put the resulting HTML into the infowindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your markers:

```
markers = handler.addMarkers(...);

_.each(markers, function(marker){
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function(){
    $.get(expectedUrl)   
      .done(function(data){
        //only you know how `data` is structured
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: 'content' });
        infowindow.open( handler.getMap(), marker.getServiceObject());
      })
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks apneadiving, this has helped me immensely in figuring out where to go. But unfortunately didn't work, using my current code. I created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/pauldacus/31d4f838a0d34b4975a6
If you can please look at it (sorry, haml formatting), and tell me if you see anything wrong, I would so appreciate it. I have been struggling with this for days now, and have exhausted every option I can think of.
The map displays fine, but clicking on markers just pans & centers, but no infowindow. I appreciate any info you or anyone else can give on this.

Comment: This is a gist of the generated js (with marker json): https://gist.github.com/pauldacus/626ccebd57b80a00b5c7

Comment: This is a gist of the controller code: https://gist.github.com/pauldacus/b26b48d3cbf000d491df
And thanks to apneadiving for creating this awesome gem!

Comment: WooHoo!  I got this working after 3 days, but there is one tiny change in apneadivings' code to make it work:
google.maps.event.addListener(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click', function () {
The service object is where the addListener event is stored. This is how I store it:
    Gmaps.store.markers = markers.map(function(m) {
    marker = Gmaps.store.handler.addMarker(m);
    marker.serviceObject.set("id",m.id);
    marker.serviceObject.set("content", "Some content");
    return marker; 
    });
Thanks again apneadiving for Gmaps4Rails & your help. Marking this correct, hope that's OK..